# React Redux way of handling enable-disable of DOM elements

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a form where i have to enable/disable certain DOM elements based on the state of other DOM elements. For e.g. I have a radio button, on the click of which a drop down should be enabled.

Now for implementing this, should I again follow the redux way of disposing an action when the radio is clicked and then within the reducer change the state and then enable/disable the dropdown?

Does redux-form in any way simplify this process? What is the best practice to implement this in a react-redux setup?

Comment: I would stick to the Redux pattern in my entire application even if some other package offered me a "simplified" version of doing the same thing for a special case. But that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

I use redux-form for conditional inputs. For example, I have a checkbox that when checked, should display a text area to explain the true input. That looks like this:

```
        <div className="checkbox">
          <label for="trueInput">
          <input type="checkbox" {...trueInput} />
          Is this input true?</label>
        </div>

        <div className={!trueInput.value ? 'conditional-input' : ''}>
          <label for="trueInputExplanation">Why is this input true?</label>
          <input className="form-control" {...trueInputExplanation} />
        </div>
```

The class .conditional-input has styling to hide the element. I'd imagine you could do this the same way for disabled, by way of using a ternary function that returns true or false, depending on the conditions you need.

Answer (score 1):

Redux Form keeps track of everything in the store. (It's easy to see what's going on with the Redux Chrome dev tool.)  Say I have a master checkbox whose enablement allows me to toggle a slave checkbox.  So I want to put the master state read from the form into props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const isMasterChecked = state.mySetting.isMasterChecked;
    const form_mySetting = state.form.mySetting;
    const form_isMasterChecked = form_mySetting ? form_mySetting.values.isMasterChecked : null;

return {
  isMasterChecked,
  form_isMasterChecked 
}
```

};

and then for the form you have

```
const {isMasterChecked, form_isMasterChecked} = props;

const shouldDisable_slaveCheckbox= () => {
    if (form_isMasterChecked == null) return isMasterChecked; // the form is not fully built yet, so use "real" store value instead of reading the form via store
    return form_isMasterChecked;
};

<Field name="isSlaveChecked" component="input" type="checkbox" disabled={shouldDisable_slaveCheckbox() ? "" : "disabled"}/>
```

Use sparingly, as this approach may cause entire form redraw.